# &nbsp; is showing as Â and inline css is removed in hotmail while I sent newsletter using php mail()

Tags: php, html, css, email

I sent the newsletter using php `mail()`. In gmail it is rendering fine but in hotmail it removed some inline css like `float:left or right;` is removed from html and also it is showing `&nbsp;` as `Â`.

Comment: What charset are you using? How have you set that in your HTML - in a `meta` tag? (Please get into the habit of providing enough information to help answer the question. Ask yourself: "if I saw this question, what extra information would I need to actually answer it?").

Comment: Solved by adding 

    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

Comment: `float` is not supported in Outlook and Outlook.com, so I guess the same goes for Hotmail. You should instead use the html element `align=""` in your table cells. You are using tables right?

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere the non-breaking spaces from the HTML template (the  s) are encoding as `ISO-8859-1` so that they show up incorrectly as an `"Â"` character

To fix this problem, you need to either parse HTML using `ISO-8859-1` or echo the results using `UTF-8`. I'd recommend to use `UTF-8` all the way. Go through the PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet to align it all out.

http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't really use/rely on using css in HTML emails as they are HTML. I would suggest you rewrite your email template using pure html and tables. 
See the following links:

http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/ultimate-guide-html-emails/

Good luck with this one as HTML emails can ruin lives.